# Can a Filter Formula return multiple values?

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have a tracker that when the user puts a "V" in a cell it will populate in another sheet that users name. To get the information I am using this formula

```
=IFNA(JOIN(", ", FILTER(Input!$A$5:$A$30, Input!Q5:Q="V")))
```

The question I have is how to look for "V" and "H" values. I have tried several combinations of If statements and also

```
=IFNA(JOIN(", ", FILTER(Input!$A$5:$A$30, Input!Q5:Q="V", "H")))
```

But none work. This is a link to a sample setup

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c-KYphQwpMuT2IK9ezHms4DqbyL0fjgSksPFwBhLJXU/edit?usp=sharing

ALSO this document is being used on a corporate account and we do not have the ability to run custom functions.

I updated the link if it still doesn't work I apologize.

Comment: Please consider make the Sheet open to anyone with the link so we can access it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(JOIN(", ", FILTER(Input!A5:A30, REGEXMATCH(Input!Q5:Q30, "V|H"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not access your spreadsheet, but see if this works

```
=IFNA(JOIN(", ", FILTER(Input!$A$5:$A$30, (Input!Q5:Q30="V")+(Input!Q5:Q30="H"))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the REGEXMATCH worked and was cleaner. I tried this one earlier in my attempts. .

Comment: The ranges weren't set correctly. Should be okay now.